# use bash and sed with a filename that includes a dynamic hash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script in my application that configures a few API paths based on the docker environment running the script. The following code works great if the filename is static, however when Angular CLI builds a production version of the application it adds a hash to the filename. How would I tell the bash script to use any filename that fits a pattern? For example how would I find the filename `main.28ce25b7ef460b2617ae.bundle.js` where the hash could be anything?

My script works with non-prod builds that don't add the hash

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's|placeholder_base_service_endpoint|'$BASE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT'|g' main.bundle.js
```

I tried using a wildcard but it doesn't appear to have been able to find the file as the string wasn't replaced.

```
main.*.bundle.js
```

Comment: What did not work? What was the error message? Use `set -x` before the sed line and show us the output.

Comment: Could be we're on a `sed` version (such as MacOS) where the optarg to `sed -i` specifying backup extension is mandatory -- but we can't possibly know for sure without an exact error message.

Comment: `files=( main.*.bundle.js )` will populate an array called `files` with your matches.

Comment: BTW, one way `main.*.bundle.js` won't be replaced is if no files matching the glob exist at that point in the build process.

Comment: Anyhow, if you want us to be able to build a fix for this issue, you'll need to describe how to create it. `echo foo > main.WHATEVER.bundle.js; sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' main.*.bundle.js` works perfectly fine, for example, on any platform that has GNU (as opposed to BSD or baseline-POSIX) `sed`. So, if I can give you an example you can just copy-and-paste that demonstrably *doesn't* cause the problem, can you give us an example that can be copied-and-pasted but *does*? (See also the docs on building a [mcve]).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `files=( ... )` worked. Please add it as a answer and I'll select it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### On Glob Expansions

If you want a glob to be expanded during an assignment, one way to do so is to expand into an array:

```
files=( main.*.bundle.js )
```

As some extra paranoia, you might consider sanity-checking the resulting array:

```
die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; } # define a "die" function to exit if a test fails

[[ -L ${files[0]} || -e ${files[0]} ]] || die "Glob main.*.bundle.js had no matches"
(( ${#files[@]} == 1 )) || die "More than one match for main.*.bundle.js found"
```

If instead of asserting that there's only one match you want to put *all* matches on your `sed` (or another) command line, you can do that with `"${files[@]}"`.

#### On `sed -i`

Note that on some platforms (notably MacOS), `sed -i` requires an argument giving a file extension to use for backups. To work reliably on such platforms, passing an empty string is appropriate:

```
sed -i '' \
    -e 's|placeholder_base_service_endpoint|'"$BASE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT"'|g' \
   "${files[@]}"
```

Note that after the single-quoted string is ended, a double-quoted string is started before expanding `BASE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT`; that way we avoid issues if that string can be treated as a glob or split into multiple shell words.

Of course, `"${files[@]}"` could also just be the literal glob `main.*.bundle.js`.